# asp.net mvc ViewEngineResult FindView and virtual path provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewengine

What role ViewEngineResult FindView method plays in asp.net mvc, can we change the view location in this method. I can understand VirtualPathProvider but have some confusion about FindView method.

Help will be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `FindView` method has the role of locating the corresponding view given its name. You can write a custom view engine if you want to change the location where ASP.NET MVC is looking for views. Here's an [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx) which provides an example of how to achieve this.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov If Views folder `A` contains a view `Index` and Views folder `B` also contains a view `Index`, what does `FindView` return when called from a method in Controllers folder `A`?